# cref change section naming scheme in spanish

Tags: cross-referencing, babel, cleveref, spanish

## Intro

I am writing a report in spanish. When using `\cref{sec:section}` to reference a subsection, I get a name I don't want: "apartado". I want to change this to "sección".

I know that the prefered way is to use `\addto\captionsitalian{\renewcommand{\THING1}{NAME_I_WANT}}` where THING1 comes from Table 8 [here](https://tug.org/pracjourn/2007-1/gregorio/gregorio.pdf).

I don't see any THING1 that refers to section/subsections, so I cannot seem to change "apartado" to something else. I did try with `\partname`.

## Minimal Working Example

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, spanish]{report}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Ch1}
\section{Sec1}
\subsection{SubSec1}
\label{sec:ss1}
\subsubsection{SSS1}
\subsection{SubSec2}

\section{Sec1}
As seen in \cref{sec:ss1}.
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

### What I would like:

Same as previous image with "apartado" changed by "sección", "subsección" or "subsubsección" where applicable.

If this were impossible, I would like to change "apartado" for "sección" (without "subsección" or "subsubsección").

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command of the `cleveref` package you want to use is called `\crefname`. It takes three arguments: the name of a LaTeX counter (usually a noun) along with the desired singular and plural nominative-case forms of the noun.

[image]

Here, I've included the definite article (la, las) in the arguments of `\crefname`. If you would rather set `\crefname{subsection}{sección}{secciónes}`, you can of course do so, but you'll have to supply la/las by hand.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, spanish]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\crefname{subsection}{la sección}{las secciónes}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{chapter}{2}
\section{Sec1}
\subsection{SubSec1}\label{sec:ss1}
\subsection{SubSec2}\label{sec:ss2}

\section{Sec1}
Como se ve en \cref{sec:ss1}, \dots

Como se ve en \cref{sec:ss1,sec:ss2}, \dots
\end{document}
```

Comment: I feel pretty dumb. It's literally the first entry in the "Customising Individual Cross-Reference Types" subsection in the [docs](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/cleveref/cleveref.pdf). Thanks!

For reference for other that come accross this, I think [this](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Counters) contains a list of the "LaTeX counters" for the first argument.